# How to stop the page from refreshing and from loosing the users input on an unssucceful post request

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a Merin Stack where a user can make a comment on a Program, and i am also using Google-react-Recaptcha to prevent spamming.

Everything is working well, except when a user forgets to declare that they are not a robot(to check the Recaptcha box) and the post request becomes unsuccessful. what happens is that the input that the user typed clears and it seems that the page is refreshing on a failed post request.

How do I make the user's inputs not clear from the field on a failed post request?

Here is my `onSubmit` function

```
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const [token, setToken] = useState("");
const reCaptcha = useRef();





const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
  if (!token) {
    alert("Yoou must verify the captcha");
    setError("Yoou must verify the captcha");
  }
  setError("");
  e.preventDefault();
  setName("");
  setDescription("");

  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:9000/programs/" +
        props.match.params.id +
        "/programcomment",
      { name: name, description: eventDescription, token }
    )

    .then(function (response) {
      onPageLoad();
      alert("Submitted Succefully");
    })

    .catch(function (err) {
      setError(err);
      console.log(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      reCaptcha.current.reset();
      setToken("");
    });
  });
```

and my form inputs

```
    <div className="container">
        <div className="row " />
        <div className="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div className="col-sm-10"></div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-2" />
          <div className="col-sm-10">
            <form className="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="name"
                  value={name}
                  required
                  onChange={handleChange("name")}
                />
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="comment">Comment:</label>
                <textarea
                  className="form-control"
                  rows={5}
                  id="comment"
                  required
                  defaultValue={""}
                  value={eventDescription}
                  onChange={handleChange("description")}
                />
                <br />
              </div>
              <ReCAPTCHA
                ref={reCaptcha}
                sitekey="6LecT-sZgfgrrtrtrtrtqQuMSJnMbxrif0ArqJqk2"
                onChange={(token) => setToken(token)}
                onExpired={(e) => setToken("")}
              />

              <button
                type="submit"
                id="myBtn"
                class="btn btn-success"
                // onClick={handleSubscribe}
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>

            <p id="warning" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an else section and move preventdefault to beginning.

```
const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!token) {
    alert("Yoou must verify the captcha");
    setError("Yoou must verify the captcha");
  }
  else{
    setError("");
    setName("");
    setDescription("");

  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:9000/programs/" +
        props.match.params.id +
        "/programcomment",
      { name: name, description: eventDescription, token }
    )

    .then(function (response) {
      onPageLoad();
      alert("Submitted Succefully");
    })

    .catch(function (err) {
      setError(err);
      console.log(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      reCaptcha.current.reset();
      setToken("");
    });
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `e.preventDefault();` to your `onSubmit` callback and wrap to `else` block code which is invoked after checking token:

```
const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!token) {
    alert("Yoou must verify the captcha");
    setError("Yoou must verify the captcha");
  } else {
    setError("");
    e.preventDefault();
    setName("");
    setDescription("");

    axios
      .post(
        "http://localhost:9000/programs/" +
          props.match.params.id +
          "/programcomment",
        { name: name, description: eventDescription, token }
      )

      .then(function (response) {
        onPageLoad();
        alert("Submitted Succefully");
      })

      .catch(function (err) {
        setError(err);
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        reCaptcha.current.reset();
        setToken("");
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @RukkiesMan I did try it but it didn't work, it only prevents the page from refreshing but the inputs still clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault at the beginning of your onSubmit function maybe ?

```
const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks. i did try it but it didn't work, it only prevents the page from refreshing but the inputs still clears. @Versifiction